# Matrix of a Linear Transformation on a Polynomial Space

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm trying to find the matrix of the linear transformation: $T: \mathcal{P}_1 \to \mathcal{P}_2, T(p(x)) = p(x+1)$ in the standard basis. I got that $T(1) = 2, T(x) = x+1$, so I got that the matrix is \begin{pmatrix}2&1\\ 0&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}
But this doesn't seem to be right since if I test it on $p(x)=2$, then I get that $T(2) = 4$. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $T(1)=1$ because there is no $x$ in $1$ to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The first element of the standard basis is the constant polinomial $p_1(x)=1$. Then $p_1(x+1)=1$ and then the first column of your desired matrix would be 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$